# Compactness result

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, compactness

I try to prove this lemma:

[image]

> Let $\mathrm{H}_{\text{comp}}^1(\Bbb R^{\mathrm{N}})$ be the subspace of $\mathrm{H}^1(\Bbb R^{\mathrm{N}})$ of functions with compact support. For each $u\in\mathrm{H}_{\text{comp}}^1(\Bbb R^{\mathrm{N}})$ and $u\ne 0$, let
>
> $$\beta(u)=\frac{\int_{\Bbb R_\mathrm{N}}|\nabla u(x)|^2x\,dx}{\int_{\Bbb R_\mathrm{N}}|\nabla u(x)|^2\,dx}\;.$$
>
> From known results about compactness (*see* [$8$] and [$5$], theorem I.$6$) it is easy to prove the following lemma:
>
> **Lemma** $\mathbf{1.1.}$ – *For each* $\rho>0$ *there is an* $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$ *such that*
>
> $$\frac{\|u\|^2}{|u|_{2^*}^{2^*}}\le\mathrm{S}+\varepsilon\quad\implies\quad\beta\left(\frac{u}{|u|_{2^*}}\right)\in\Omega_\rho^+\;.$$

Where [$8$] is [here](http://dmle.cindoc.csic.es/), and [$5$] is [here](https://eudml.org/doc/173508).

Can you tell me how we can prove this?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm curious: what are you reading in French? Is it a book or a paper?

Comment: It is a paper of Monica Lazzo 1992 @Siminore